# How evm works on neon blockchain in Solana context

Tags: solana-program, ethereum, neon-evm

Neon is the first evm compatible chain for Solana.

I want to talk here about binance smart chain here which is evm compatible meaning has evm runtime built in the Binance chain. so you can create an app targeting stable evm which is capable to run on Binance smart chain. taking the advantage of evm stability and binance,less gas fees.

so how does neon works in this context? both in context for Solana and Ethereum. neon is built on Solana? you can build new blockchains on Solana?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation here that describes how it works? I haven't yet myself, but just found it and thought it might answer your questions.

https://docs.neon-labs.org/docs/architecture/neon_evm_arch